# Accessing protected const in method defined in parent

Tags: php

I have an abstract base class that extends into a child class. In the base class, I have

```php
protected CONST TYPE = '';
```

which in the child class gets overwritten by

```php
protected CONST TYPE = 'mysql';
```

In the parent, I defined

```php
public function getTableName() {
    /*
    Code here
    */
    var_dump(self::TYPE); exit;
}
```

Even though I call `$this->getTableName()` in the child class, it dumps an empty string. I'm guessing I'm not understanding scoping here; given it's called by the child, isn't the scope relative to the child? Or since it's defined by the parent, will it always be in the scope of the parent? Is this a problem with constants? I'm running PHP 7.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because once a constant is defined with a value, it remains that value. Which is intended because the value is meant to be "constant"

You should instead use `protected static $type = ''`

Comment: Ok. I figured since it was overwritten in the child, the value would scope to the child.

Comment: That's a fair thought but the parent must exist before the child can extend it, a child is merely a layer above the parent that adds additional functionality, it can't change constants already defined